# How to Connect and Write Orbita Card Reader C# application through the window service

Tags: c#

Currently, I'm doing Hotel online Booking system. So far I did almost 80 percent of work. Now I have a problem to connect smart card reader in the C# application and also need to be written on that card.

For example:
When Arrived Customer at the hotel he needs to be book the room in the reception. So in the hotel receipient, Giving a card to them to used to open the door using this card system. In the card, we want to insert some information there.for example for customer checking time and checkout time.

The Hotel Now they Currently using Orbita lock Mifare encoder, smart card reader. I want to connect this card to my application and write the information into that card using the above card reader.

Could you all help me above issue I'm new to this Orbita lock Mifare encoder, smart card reader

Code

```
      string strException = string.Empty;
        string strComPort = "COM17";
        int nBaudrate=Convert.ToInt32(9600);

        int nRet = OpenCom(strComPort, nBaudrate, out strException);
        if (nRet != 0)
        {
            string strLog = "Connect reader failed, due to: " + strException; 

            //return;
        }
        else
        {
            string strLog = "Reader connected " + strComPort + "@" + nBaudrate.ToString();

        }
```

above this code i used to connect but not connecting and when write the information i dont have any idea how to write what code used to write

Comment: You need to be more specific about the real problem. Put the code you have tried until now.

Comment: any body help please...................

Comment: Meanwhile, we can try to provide what help is possible. When it fails to connect, what exact error message do you see?

Comment: Error says Cannot not connect device

Comment: Not sure why my earlier comment on this subject was removed, so I'll ask again: Have you sought or received any documentation or other support about this device, either from the vendor or the manufacturer? That would hopefully contain technical details about connecting it

Comment: Still yet to receive it.in the mean time i tried to connect it device but error.so you are saying that documentation tell everything how we connect and how to write right?

Comment: Well I hope it would at least point you in the right direction. Obviously I don't know exactly what it will say. But it should hopefully give some useful info about settings, or protocols to use, installing drivers, any existing SDK software which you might be able to use, etc. There may be a more sophisticated way to use it than a simple port connection